# Can't import NumPy from site-packages of a different conda env

Tags: numpy, conda

I have 2 conda environments (on macOS Big Sur) `old_base` and `new_base`, both with NumPy (1.19.4) installed. I noticed something odd. When my env is `old_base` but cwd is the `site-packages` directory of `new_base`, I can't import NumPy.

```
$ (old_base) cd /Users/joshfriedlander/anaconda3/envs/new_base/lib/python3.8/site-packages
$ (old_base) which python
/Users/joshfriedlander/anaconda3/envs/old_base/bin/python
$ python
Python 3.8.6 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Oct  7 2020, 18:42:56)
[Clang 10.0.1 ] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/joshfriedlander/anaconda3/envs/new_base/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
  File "/Users/joshfriedlander/anaconda3/envs/new_base/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.py", line 12, in <module>
    from . import overrides
  File "/Users/joshfriedlander/anaconda3/envs/new_base/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/overrides.py", line 7, in <module>
    from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/joshfriedlander/anaconda3/envs/new_base/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 140, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "/Users/joshfriedlander/anaconda3/envs/new_base/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError:

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html

Please note and check the following:

  * The Python version is: Python3.8 from "/Users/joshfriedlander/anaconda3/envs/interns/bin/python"
  * The NumPy version is: "1.19.1"

and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

Original error was: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'
```

Nothing on the linked help page seems relevant. From any other location I tested, including `~/anaconda3/envs/old_base/lib/python3.8/site-packages`, importing NumPy works without a hitch.

What's going on here?

(Obviously this isn't an issue for me, I'm just curious about why it happens.)

Comment: This is probably because the `numpy/` directory in the cwd is shadowing the directory from your path.

Comment: Ah, this is probably the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify? Does the `new_base` (i.e. `bar`) have two different `lib` folders, because you are doing `cd .../bar/lib/python3.8/site-packages`, but later it is `.../new_base/lib/python3.7/site-packages`. Maybe use your actual env names instead of trying to replace them with foo/bar, to avoid confusion

Comment: @FlyingTeller done. Seems pretty clear that Nils Werner's hunch was right.